# What does this notation mean: $\|\cdot \|_F$

Tags: notation, absolute-value, machine-learning

For context, [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1811.05320.pdf) defines the following equation as the accuracy metric for their function:

$$ Acc(\hat{Y}) = 1-\frac{\|Y-\hat{Y}\|_F}{\|Y\|_F} $$

I assume it's probably just a weird notation the authors made up, but I want to make sure I'm not missing anything. Google has been no help, and I can't find any other mention of that symbol in the paper. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very likely the Frobenius norm, sort of the fundamental norm (Euclidean norm) over matrices : https://mathworld.wolfram.com/FrobeniusNorm.html

Comment: I think you're right. This makes a lot of sense in the context of the paper as well